# Merging small polygons into larger adjacent polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge

I wish to select just the small green polygons (see image) and merge these with the pink polygon. However, I wish to leave the large green polygons that are over 1km2. However, all the green is one polygon, when I select one small area every green polygon is selected.

Any ideas?

[image: See image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use the processing tool "multiparts to singleparts" before: this will convert the multipolygon (the green one) into single polygons which you can join/merge afterwards.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There are over 500 small green patches are you aware of a fast way to merge them without clicking on them one by one? If I select an area with multiple qgis crashes?

Answer (score 5):

After `multipart to singlepart` as @eurojam suggested, you may select all green areas smaller than `1 sqkm` by pasting the expression `$area<1000000` into the `select by expression` dialogue. Your green layer has to use a m-based CRS in order for this to work properly. You then may merge the selected green areas with the other layer as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

After converting your Multipart polygons to single part, use the 'Eliminate selected Polygon feature' in QGIS it will merge the selected small polygons to the adjacent Polygons according to the method that you select from this tool